# Infinite dimensional Gram-Schmidt

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Given an **infinite** dimensional inner product space $(V,\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle)$, with a countable Hamel basis, is it always possible to perform the Gram--Schmidt process and produce an orthonormal basis for 
$(V,\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle)$? (To be precise, by orthonormal basis I mean a Hamel basis $\{e_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\langle e_i,e_j \rangle) = \delta_{ij}$, for all $i,j$?

Comment: I guess you mean *Schauder* basis. And yes, it works.

Comment: I think the OP means Hamel basis (i.e., basis in the sense of linear algebra - a linearly independent spanning set). And yes it works: just keep extending an orthonormal bsis for the span of the first $n$ elements of the Hamel basis to an orthonormal basis for the span of the first $n+1$ elements.

Comment: @copper.hat Of course, it can. For example the space of all sequences with only finitely many non-zero terms.

Comment: @Jochen: You are correct, I was thinking F-space which needs completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and this is quite straightforward. Let $(v_n)$ be  a Hamel basis. Having found an orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ for the span of $v_1,v_2,..,v_n$ we can always find coefficients $c_j$ such that $e_{n+1}=\sum c_je_j+c_{n+1} v_{n+1}$  has norm $1$ and is orthogonal to $e_i: i \leq n$.

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking F-space which needs completeness.